# Как нужно исправить нейросеть?

Tags: python-3.x, нейронные-сети, фильтры

Недавно начал пробовать себя в создании нейросетей, так что не бейте.
Я попытался сделать нейросеть, которая как бы накладывает фильтр на изображение, основываясь на уже готовом примере.

Моя нейросеть имеет вид: *3 входных* нейрона (Пиксель в кодировке RGB) и *3 выходных* нейрона соответственно,
все нейроны входного слоя соединены со всеми нейрона выходного слоя, функция активации - сигмоида.

Прошу объяснить мне, почему это работает не так, как я хочу

Код нейросети:

```
import numpy
from PIL import Image
import scipy.special
import datetime


class neuralNetwork:

    def __init__(self, inputnodes, outputnodes, learningrate):
        self.inodes = inputnodes
        self.onodes = outputnodes

        self.wio = numpy.load('Input_out.npy')

        self.lr = learningrate

        self.activation_function = lambda x: scipy.special.expit(x)

        pass

    def train(self, inputs_list, targets_list):
        inputs = numpy.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T
        targets = numpy.array(targets_list, ndmin=2).T

        output_inputs = numpy.dot(self.wio, inputs)

        final_outputs = self.activation_function(output_inputs)

        output_errors = targets - final_outputs

        self.wio += self.lr * numpy.dot((output_errors * final_outputs * (1.0 - final_outputs)),
                                        numpy.transpose(inputs))


        numpy.save('Input_out', self.wio)
        pass

    def query(self, inputs_list):
        inputs = numpy.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T

        final_inputs = numpy.dot(self.wio, inputs)
        final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)

        return final_outputs

input_nodes = 3
output_nodes = 3

learning_rate = 0.2

n = neuralNetwork(input_nodes, output_nodes, learning_rate)
img_input = Image.open('img_input22.png') # Входное изображение
img_output = Image.open('img_output22.png') # Выходное изображение

pixels_input = img_input.load() # список с пикселями
pixels_output = img_output.load() # список с пикселями
width, height = img_input.size # ширина и высота изображения
print("РАЗМЕР:", width, "x",height)



e = 5 # Кол-во эпох

for i in range(e):

    for x in range(width):

        for y in range(height):
            training_inputs = numpy.array(pixels_input[x, y]) / 255
            training_outputs = numpy.array(pixels_output[x, y]) / 255
            n.train(training_inputs, training_outputs)


    clock = datetime.datetime.today()
    print("Эпоха номер", str(i + 1), "закончилась", "(Время: " + str(clock.hour) + "ч " + str(clock.minute) + "мин)")

print()
print("Обучение завершено!")

def change_image(filename):
    test = Image.open(filename)
    pix = test.load()
    x, y = test.size
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            r, g, b = n.query(pix[i, j])

            r1 = int(round(r[0] * 255))
            g1 = int(round(g[0] * 255))
            b1 = int(round(b[0] * 255))
            pix[i, j] = r1, g1, b1

    test.save(filename.split(".")[0] + "_change.png")

change_image("img_input22.png")
```

[image: Работа нейросети]

Comment: Нейрофильтры для обработки изображений обычно получают на вход не 1 пиксель, а квадратную матрицу пикселей. Ну там, 4х4 или 8х8. Попробуй создать 3 (три) отдельных сетки - по одной на каждый цветовой канал. У каждой будет 4 входных нейрона, чтобы скормить ей квадрат 2х2 пикселя.

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько возможных причин. Во-первых возможно следует увеличить количество эпох. Во-вторых проблема может быть в некорректных начальных весах. В-третьих можно добавить скрытые слои для улучшения результата.

Comment: я пробовал 35 эпох (это примерно 3.5 ч обучения), результат тот же. Веса задаются случайным образом (это не влияет на конечный результат, так как у меня уже были попытки с другими фильтрами). Когда я добавлял скрытые слои, то вместо хоть какого-то результата мне выдавало полную ересь.

Answer (score 0):

Обучение сети всегда начинается с модуля numpy.random, у вас его нет.